# Eighth notes beamed over quarter note notation guitar part

Tags: guitar, notation

Please could someone clarify what the highlighted note combination means?
The source is the song "Paint it Black" sheet music for guitar and piano.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Just a hint for any future questions you may want to ask. it is considered courteous on this site not to accept the first answer to your question but to wait a day and then accept an answer, this gives everyone a fair chance to bid for your acceptance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quite simple:

The 3. verse contains two syllable below the 2nd. quarter **(Maybe)** and the 2. verse two syllable below the 4th. quarter **(people)**

so if you play or sing the tune of the 3. verse you have to play or sing 2 eight notes, and dito in the 2. verse.

Comment: Nice!  FWIW,  in instrumental music, with more formal notation, the "alternate" notes would be marked with a "2" or "3" to indicate on which verses they should be used.

Comment: An alternative version for notating this is to write it as 2 eight notes tied together, but the tie is a dotted or dashed line instead of a solid. So in the verse where the lyrics are one syllable, the tie applies and otherwise sing it as separate eight notes